# ?Docker commit -run '--- deprecated, will be removed soon , how to replace

Tags: docker

How should I commit my command and port mapping in a short future ?

```
docker commit -run '{"Cmd": ["/usr/bin/mongod", "--smallfiles"], "PortSpecs": [":27017"]}' 24f7c erwin16/mongodb
Warning: '-run' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
661c41b0925effe07b5d272a5e400f3147cca4f52b655d287c2c8a87b041a37e
```

the usage  doc doesn't mention it ...

update1 :

```
yves@MacMini: ~ $ docker -v
Docker version 1.7.0, build 0baf609
```

Comment: can you post `docker version` ?

Comment: updated my question w Docker version thanks for your attention